# are there infinitely many primes in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

There is one proof about infinitude of prime with following method,

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2271540

Also it is well know that any two consecutive Fibonacci numbers are mutually prime.

My question, can the proof be used for proving there  are infinitely many primes in Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: That link is broken. Does it require to be logged in, or is the site just down?

Comment: This is still an [open problem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime) unless a proof has been announced in the last few hours and the news has not spread.

Comment: The author proves that there are infinitely many primes as follows: Let N1>1. Then N1 and N1+1 are coprime because they are consecutive integers, so N2=N1(N1+1) has at least two distinct prime factors. Likewise, N2 and N2+1 are consecutive integers, so N3=N2(N2+1) must have at least three distinct prime factors. As this process may be continued indefinitely, the number of primes is infinite.====>this is the proof, FYI

Comment: @André Nicolas, yeth, it is still open problem.. my question is that if one can prove it with the method in previous my comment. Thanks.

Comment: That is an attractive proof of the infinitude of primes, structurally related to the one that uses Fermat Numbers. If the idea could be used in a not too complicated way to settle the Fibonacci primes problem, it probably would have been long ago. Probably, not certainly.

Comment: @André Nicolas, there was one proof using Fermat Numbers, but this one is quite simple if you read above my comment. It's proved that 2 consecutive Fibonacci numbers were coprime,  thus it is very easy to setup the proof by several lines by following the same rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you apply that method to the Fibonacci numbers you get (at best) that there are infinitely many primes dividing Fibonacci numbers. This doesn't imply that there are infinitely many Fibonacci primes.

Comment: that's clear. THANKS! So here we have "another" proof that there are infinitely many prime via Fibonacci number, which just like Fermat numbers way :)

Answer (score 1):

> So that's what I mean when I ask if there are infinitely many prime Fibonacci numbers, and not only do we not know the answer, in some sort of technical way we are very, very far from knowing the answer. **This is considered to be a very difficult problem.**

https://youtu.be/LvFvtjn3wgg?t=2121 at 35:21

'Experimenting with Primes' - Dr Holly Krieger, Lecturer in the Department of Pure Mathematics and Mathematical Statistics and Corfield Fellow in Mathematics at Murray Edwards College, University of Cambridge

[image]